# Consumer reads data twice from avro schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, schema, avro

I have a streaming app where it listens to some data and then transforming the data by pushing the data into a new topic. I use avro schema for both to read/write my data into topics. The problem is when i consume the data from the final destination by using the command in the below. However, my data is a little complex with some array and json inside of it and i suspect that my avro schemas might not be correct for my purpose.  There is no error or anything, I can see all my data on my final topic but the "Pets" field are duplicated for some reason and i can't understand why. In fact, i only add one new field (job_id) to my existing data in the avro schema, i don't make big changes on it when i transform it.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --topic my_topic \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
```

Here's the json data i have

```
{
   "Person":{
      "id":"104440",
      "Name":"William",
      "LastName":"Dorsey",
      "archived":false,
      "Timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
      "brandCompanyName":"Twitter",
      "brandID":"cf545a7b",
      "creatorID":"1234",
      "currency":"USD",
      "dateCreated":"2020-09-07T02:56:22Z",
      "dateModified":"2020-09-07T02:57:24Z",
      "disabled":false,
      "endDate":"2020-11-29T19:51:00-08:00",
      "startDate":"2020-08-31T20:55:00-07:00",
      "totalBudget":0
   },
   "Pets":[
      {
         "Name":"Pawny",
         "Id":"4214",
         "budget":"0",
         "adoptionDate":"2020-09-07T02:56:22Z",
         "year":"2",
         "type":"Golden",
         "gender":"male"
      }
   ],
   "CreationTime":"1604036638"
}
```

my avro schema

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Person",
      "type": {
        "name": "Person",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "Name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "LastName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "archived",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          {
            "name": "Timezone",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "brandCompanyName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "brandID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "creatorID",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "currency",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "dateCreated",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "dateModified",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "disabled",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          {
            "name": "endDate",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "startDate",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "totalBudget",
            "type": "int"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Pets",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "name": "Pets_record",
          "type": "record",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "Name",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "Id",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "budget",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "adoptionDate",
              "type": "int",
              "logicalType": "date"
            },
            {
              "name": "year",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "gender",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "CreationTime",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name":"jobID",
      "type":"string"
    }
  ]
}
```

the output in my topic when i consume the topic - the pets field are duplicated for some reason? I can't figure out why

```
{
      "id":"104440",
      "Name":"William",
      "LastName:"Dorsey",
      "archived":false,
      "Timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
      "brandCompanyName":"Twitter",
      "brandID":"cf545a7b",
      "creatorID":"1234",
      "currency":"USD",
      "dateCreated":"2020-09-07T02:56:22Z",
      "dateModified":"2020-09-07T02:57:24Z",
      "disabled":false,
      "endDate":"2020-11-29T19:51:00-08:00",
      "startDate":"2020-08-31T20:55:00-07:00",
      "totalBudget":0,
      "Pets":[
      {
         "Name":"Pawny",
         "Id":"4214",
         "budget":"0",
         "adoptionDate":2020-09-07T02:56:22Z",
         "year":"2",
         "type":"Golden",
         "gender":"male"
      }
   ],
   "CreationTime":1604036638,
   "jobID":12512,
   "pets":[
      {
         "Name":"Pawny",
         "Id":"4214",
         "budget":"0",
         "adoptionDate":2020-09-07T02:56:22Z",
         "year":"2",
         "type":"Golden",
         "gender":"male"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you use for transforming the data? It will help diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because i was using Uppercase name in my field names... Wandering in endless loops for 24 hours, i was finally able to figure out this if anyone ran into same issue. Please read here and use lowercase name for your fieldnames. When i changed my field name to "pet". The duplicates are gone